# Prevent Nuget from downloading the most updated version of a dependency

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I used Nuget for downloading a specific version of **CouchbaseClient** which is a .Net client for a NoSql product.

This dll has a dependency in Newton.Json , so this is what happened when using Nuget:

```
Install-Package CouchbaseNetClient -Version 1.3.6
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5'.
Installing 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.6'.
Successfully installed 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.6'.
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5' to DataAccess.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5' to DataAccess.
Adding 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.6' to DataAccess.
Successfully added 'CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.6' to DataAccess.
```

The problem is, that when i ran the unit tests an exception was thrown that it is looking for Newton.Json version 4.5.0.

So , i needed to remove manually the Newton.Json 6.0.5 that Nuget downloaded for me and added with Nuget Newton.Json 4.5.0.

Is there a simpler way to do it?
I do not want to do this manual process each time i will download a package with dependencies which are not the most updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

1. Add a binding redirect for Newtonsoft.Json in your app.config so 4.5 is redirected to 6.0.5.
2. Add a [constraint](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions) to your packages.config to restrict the Newtonsoft.Json package version.
3. Install a more recent NuGet version (2.5 or above).
4. Use the [-DependencyVersion parameter](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) to change the default behaviour of Install-Package.
5. Create a project template with your required NuGet packages and re-use that.

If Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11 was already installed then CouchbaseNetClient would not install a later version unless you do not have Newtonsoft.Json installed already or you are using an old version of NuGet (older than NuGet 2.5).

Comment: I am using Nuget 2.8 and the solution i added the package is a new one i created from scratch.

So if i understood you right:
1. Do i have to know from advance the version of the dependency of each package i add from Nuget to prevent it from adding the most updated version?  How is it that Nuget cannot know the wanted version of the dependency?

Comment: The reason i am looking for a more proper solution is that i do not want to add manually in the packages.config the dependency version in each project i have..it is usually something people in a big team can miss doing.

I am looking for a solution that will make this process as automatic as possible and not something people need to remember doing manually in each new project.

Comment: 1. NuGet will not know what your project's requirements are for dependencies. By default it will pick the latest stable NuGet package version. The Install-Package does have a -DependencyVersion parameter which can be used to change the behaviour. 2. The dependencies in a NuGet package are defined by a manifest file (.nuspec). For the CouchbaseNetClient NuGet package it does not specify a version for the Newtonsoft.Json dependency so NuGet will take the latest by default.

Comment: I would look at creating a project template that includes the NuGet packages you need.

Comment: So you say that the team that added CouchbaseNetClient to Nuget forgot to add a dependency in the .nuspec and this is why me and all the users that install this package need to do it by ourselves manually?

Comment: No I am not saying that. If you look at most NuGet packages they do not specify explicit versions for a dependency. Some do. Those that do will add explicit version or range of versions for compatibility reasons. If the CouchbaseNetClient added a version for the Json.NET dependency it would limit its use. CouchbaseNetClient is compiled against Newtonsoft.Json 4.5. If Newtonsoft.Json does not change its API it will work against all future versions of Newtonsoft.Json. However it will need a binding redirect to work.

Comment: When Nuget downloaded for me Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5 the CouchbaseNetClient threw and exception of a dependency in 4.5.0 when trying to use it.

Comment: If the exception message was something like `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference` then you can fix that by adding a binding redirect or installing a version of CouchbaseNetClient that uses Newtonsoft.Json 4.5. If it is another exception then it may be another problem.

Comment: That was the exception and the CouchbaseNetClient i added i a one that uses 4.5.0 but the source problem is Nuget couldn`t know it..and i found it out only when the exception was thrown.

This is the main thing i want to avoid in similiar cases in the future when adding other new packages with dependencies.

Comment: And by the way -DependencyVersion will help only if the package auther added dependencies )-:
You can see it here:
http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/05/05/Picking-the-right-dependency-version-adding-packages-from-NuGet.aspx

Comment: When I add CouchbaseNetClient 1.3.6 to my project, without Json.NET being already added, Visual Studio adds a binding redirect into my app.config automatically.

Comment: Yeah but if you try to actually use it in unit tests for example, it throws an exception (the one you mentioned above)

Comment: It should not throw the exception if it has a binding redirect. Maybe you need to add the binding redirect to your unit test project?

Comment: My project "DataAccess" has all dlls installed by Nuget: Couchbase.dll,Enyim.Caching and Newtonsoft.Json (6.0.5).
When adding reference to "DataAccess" from "UnitTests" project, i am trying to use the "DataAccess" to approach db.

When using the class from the coucbase dll it throws the exception.

Do i need to add the Couchbase,Enyim.Caching and Newtonsoft.Json dll to "UnitTests" project also? Do i need to add there binding redirection also?

Comment: I would try just adding the binding redirects to the test project.